# Blueprism - Extract data from a web page into a collection

Tags: collections, blueprism, rpa

I am new to blue prism. I have a scenario where I am giving input (passengers details for traveling) to a travel portal and based on the input its generating a booking reference number, total cost etc. Now I want to read all the outputs into a collection but the problem is data is not tabular (cant use Get Table in read component). Its just the details of travel which are populating into textboxes. Please find attached the screen shot to have more clarity on this.

[image: image here]

How to achieve this? Any leads will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshot you've provided, this is part of the Blue Prism Advanced Consolidation Exercise ("BPTravel").

"Get Table" won't work on this data because it is not a table. As you've mentioned, the data is presented in a series of textboxes.

The way to tabularize this data would be to create a Collection in your Process and manually define each of the Field Names in the collection, then read each text field in individually to the correct column in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Read each text box data into `data item`. Create a `named collection` (i.e Collection with pre-defined column name). Loop through the `collection.column_name`(You will be getting column name as collection by using `Utility - Collection Manipulation` action and get the column names) and first add a row to `collection` and assign values to collection fields